# Docker: Npm install very slow in Ubuntu host

Tags: node.js, npm, docker, dockerfile

I created a Dockerfile for my application as shown below

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Shaun Thomas

RUN echo "deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install -y curl software-properties-common git

RUN mkdir /nodejs && curl http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/node-v0.10.38-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xvzf - -C /nodejs --strip-components=1
ENV PATH $PATH:/nodejs/bin

RUN npm install -g pm2@0.14.0
```

At the last step, npm install takes too long time to install the package (~ 55mins). How can I improve npm install speed and get a feedback of installation rather than seeming like it is hanged?

Note:

I get the following warning during the npm install

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6
```

and sometimes error

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs/-/yargs-1.3.3.tgz
```

I know that Docker build process is I/O intensive. I am using HDD and not SSD. I am looking for a solution other than changing my HDD to improve the npm install speed.

Update:

I am facing the above problem in Ubuntu 14.04. When I tried to build the same Dockerfile in Windows 8.1 using boot2docker, it is super fast (~2 minutes). This brings up the question; what configuration am I missing in Ubuntu?

Comment: dont you have network issues ? NPM is hosted over CDN, except countries like china where it can be real pain, it shold work like a charm. Otherwise, if that can fit you need, maybe you setup a ```sinopia``` server, then configure npm to use it before the ```npm install``` call.

Comment: You could create a base docker image with all `npm` modules already installed and use it as a basis to build all new images. So, when you'll call `npm install` it will only download missed modules (the ones you've added after current base image was built). Though, you'll have to update this base image from time to time, getting through full `npm install` process.

Comment: @maboiteaspam network is not the only possible problem. NPM builds all native modules during the installation, which could take quite a while on a slow machine.

Comment: indeed. especially if you run from a blank cache everytime. this said, both answers can work together.

Comment: The network speed here is 2.04Mbps for download and 1.95Mbps for upload. My plan is to make a new image as mentioned by @LeonidBeschastny which can be used later. But this issue is happening in the very first build of image from Dockerfile.

Comment: To clarify: npm is slow during the process of creating the docker image from a Windows host via boot2docker? But when building this docker image from an Ubuntu docker host (instead of Windows) then its fast?  I wonder if this is something with VirtualBox, try reinstalling virtual box on ubuntu and double check to make sure virtual box has sane defaults on no. processors etc. Is your Ubuntu host a virtual machine, dual-boot or separate computer?

Comment: @AnthonyElliott My Ubuntu host is a dual boot. I have both Ubuntu and Windows on same laptop. I am experiencing slowness problem in Ubuntu. In Windows(with boot2docker) it is very fast.

Comment: May need to toggle the virtualization setting in your windows bios/efi. Or install virtual box guest additions. Look at this answer for more details:  http://askubuntu.com/a/465078

Comment: @AnthonyElliott - You got me wrong again. The problem is in Ubuntu and it is not running in a VirtualBox. It is installed directly on HDD.

Comment: Pardon me, forgot docker on ubuntu doesn't need virtualbox. Check out the virtualization BIOS setting though, docker might need that.

Comment: I could find that this issue is related to https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7862

Comment: Try adding `--network=host` to `docker build`, a while ago that somehow helped network timeouts I encountered.